# Ajax Form submission in Google App Engine with jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

could not figure out why it is not working:

i need to send request to server, generate some fragment of html in python with meanCal method, and then  want that fragment embedded into submitting html file using calculation method and dynamically shows in dyContent div. all the processes are done by single click on submit button in a form.

any suggestions???   thanks in advance.

**the submitting html:**

```
<div id="dyContent" style="height: 200px;">
            waiting for user...
            {{ mgs }}   
</div>


<div id="leturetext">
    <form id="mean" method="post" action="/calculation">
        <select name="meanselect">
            <option value=10>example</option>
            <option value=11>exercise</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="btnMean" value="Check Results" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //$("#btnMean").live("click", function() {
  $("#mean").submit(function(){
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       url: "/meanCal",
       success: function(html) {
         $("#dyContent").html(html);
       }
     });
     return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

**python:**

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    path = self.request.path
    if doRender(self, path):
        return
    doRender(self,'index.htm')

class calculationHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    doRender(self, 'Diagnostic_stats.htm',
{'mgs' : "refreshed.", })

  def get(self):
    doRender(self, 'Diagnostic_stats.htm')



class meanHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    global GL
    index = self.request.get('meanselect'.value)
    if (index == 10):
        allData = GL.exampleData
        dataString = ','.join(map(str, allData))
        dataMean = (str)(stats.lmean(allData))
        doRender(self, 'Result.htm',
        {
        'dataIn' : dataString,
            'MEAN' : "Example Mean is: " + dataMean,
              })
        return
    else:
        allData = GL.exerciseData
        dataString = ','.join(map(str, allData))
        dataMean = (str)(stats.lmean(allData))
            doRender(self, 'Result.htm',
        {
        'dataIn' : dataString,
            'MEAN' : "Exercise Mean is: " + dataMean,
              })



def main():
  global GL
  GL = GlobalVariables()
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [('/calculation', calculationHandler),
    ('/meanCal', meanHandler),
        ('.*', MainHandler),
        ],
      debug=True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what is not working? Is it not going through your request handler? Is the returned result not correct?

Comment: when i click the submit button, the ajax should display a picture for me with the calculated results, but for some reason, the whole page refresh, but the picture did not show.

Answer (score 2):

To debug the python code in your GAE app, use the app engine launcher log on a running app:

[image: Using Google App Engine logs]

This should help clarify where the app is failing. I would also suggest sprinkling some calls to logging.info (or logging.debug) too.

e.g.:

```
import logging
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    logging.info("Mainhandler has been called.")
    path = self.request.path
    logging.info("Mainhandler called for:" + path)
    if doRender(self, path):
        return
    doRender(self,'index.htm')
```

Answer (score 1):

To submit a form via AJAX, you'd better consider using [Form Plugins](http://malsup.com/jquery/form). You will not need to build the parameter to be sent by yourself.

Also, it's better if you make sure that the form is working without javascript enabled. This way, your page will still be functional even js in browser is turned off. For visitor with js enabled, add the extra experience using AJAX.

To debug, use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) in Firefox, or WebInspector that build-in in Safari and Google Chrome. Check if the AJAX request is passing the data as you want, and check the response, is it contain the response that you want, an error message, or else.

---

Answer (score 1):

The `.submit()` method actually submits the form as if you pressed the submit button. Using jQuery, you can submit the form depending on certain conditions only, or as a response to an event.

If you want to send the form data to the server and get a response back, you need to create a data sting which is then set as a parameter in the `$.ajax()` call.

So your Javascript would look like this:

```
var optionSelected = $('#mean select option:selected').val();
var dataString = 'meanselect=' + optionselected;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   url: "/meanCal",
   success: function(html) {
     $("#dyContent").html(html);
   }
 });
```